# How to implement PostgreSQL function which gets the whole row?

Tags: postgresql, plpython

For instance I want to count null fields for each row in a table.

What argument type declaration should I use?

I tried composite type (table name as a type):

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_null (row my_table)
  RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
  return len([x for x in row if x is None])
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

But it doesn't match argument type if I call it like:

```
SELECT count_null(*) FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Postgres >= 9.3, you can accomplish this using a json conversion, like so:

```
create or replace function count_null(
    _r json
) returns integer as $$
    select
        count(1)::integer
    from
        (
            select
                row_to_json(json_each(_r)) as condensed_record
        ) as __base
    where
        condensed_record->>'value' is null;
$$ language sql immutable;

---------

select
    count_null(row_to_json(my_table))
from
    my_table;
```

This has the added benefit of using language SQL rather than plpythonu, so the query planner can optimise it to some degree.